# How to select a Mapbox Vuejs component package

Tags: vue.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm currently building a VueJS app the will have map components in different formats on multiple pages. I'm therefore evaluating some existing components:  [vue-mapbox](https://github.com/soal/vue-mapbox) and [vue-mapbox-gl](https://github.com/phegman/vue-mapbox-gl) (listed as mapbox-gl-vue on npmjs.com) and would like input on a choice criteria.

vue-mapbox has 37 stars on github and has peaked at about 86 downloads a week on npm.

vue-mapbox-gl has 87 stars on github and has seen a much more popular download history at around 1000 per week on npm.

Both projects seem to be under active development.

Apart from this difference in popularity, the main difference I see between the packages is vue-mapbox has adopted a more granular approach to creating sub-components (like markers and controls), whereas vue-mapbox-gl gives you a single map component and then you implement markers, clusters, controls, etc., withing the script tags of your base component. To my way of thinking, this is not really the 'vuejs way' where you create reusable components. However, vue-mapbox-gl is significantly more popular.

How would you choose? Or, would you skip component packages completely and write your own?

**EDIT**
Based on comments, I've updated this question.

My requirements:

- An overview map that has thousands of points and supports clustering.
- A per location map that displays a single point
- Ability a edit a single point location and integrate geocoding
- Popups on all points
- Consistent styling and features across all map variants
- Nuxt app with SSR, so ability to block SSR on maps.

Given that maps will appear on different kinds of pages, there will be some code reuse.

In a VueJS/Nuxt environment, what are the pros and cons of using vue-mapbox, mapbox-gl-vue, or writing from scratch?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but as phrased is totally opnion-based. You should rephrase it as something like "what are the strengths and weaknesses of each module". It would also help if you specify your own particular needs. (I've done one project with Mapbox-GL-JS and VueJS and found no need for a particular Vue component. YMMV.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment Steve - I'll update the question.